Impact of deactivation of CEO, CFO from the role hierarchy
our role hierarchy in Salesforce starts with CEO, CFO, and CTO etc. We have the respective users in CEO, CFO, and CFO etc defined with active status. What happens if we deactivate CEO or CFO from salesforce because they never login into Salesforce or do any functions. Will deactivating users in top-level of role hierarchy shows impact on anything? We want to free up the user licenses they are consuming.

The role hierarchy and a user's active status have very different functions. Role is part of the Salesforce sharing model. Active is just a reflection of whether or not a user is consuming a license & can use the platform.
Deactivating a user will not remove them from the role, delete the role, or do anything to the role. If your organization has sharing setup using the role hierarchy, that sharing will continue to work as usual for any records owned by the now inactive user(s) in those roles. Users may not be able to update certain records owned by inactive users unless they have specific permission that allows them to update records with inactive owners - but that also has nothing to do with roles and has everything to do with the User being inactive.
Welcome to the ecosystem. Based on a question like this, I assume you are very new to the platform - I'd recommend you take the Admin beginner trail at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/force_com_admin_beginner
